# Word or Excel Document with data from Active Directory

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, active-directory

I am struggling in this matter. I think, there should be an easy way to create a Word or Excel Document, dynamically populating it with data from Active Directory?
If I go to Data - new query - from Active Directory, it is rather complicated (and not working in my case)

Example: I want to make a simple overview of Users with Email and Telephone Number, so the users can print the Word document as their telephone list.
Upon opening it should fetch the latest data.
then it can be saved as PDF end distributed.

If I just make a powershell Query, I have this list in a simple query, but I cannot save it as formatted Word document...

Ist there a simpler approach (built-in, without 3rd party tools except Microsoft Office)?

Edit:
I now try getting the data via power query via this guide:
https://4sysops.com/archives/excel-get-transform-extract-information-from-active-directory/

It seems the best approach for me till now

Thanks!

Update 2:
With the mentioned link I managed to accomplish what I had in mind:
Direct retrieval of data from AD with auto-update function in a good output.

Comment: Use your powershell query and pipe it to: `<query> | select object <stuff_you_want> | export-csv -path c:\temp\mydata.csv`.  Then you should be able to use the suggestion below to do a mail merge into word.  [This page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/239938/export-ad-users-to-csv-file.html) shows it being done with AD users but the concept should be the same. @CharlesKenyon has the same thing that I would have added at the end and don't want to steal his points! :)

Answer (score 0):

### I would simply do a directory or catalog mail merge within Word and keep the data in an Excel spreadsheet.

Here is an excellent tutorial on using such mail merge tools:
[Catalogue/Directory Mail Merge Tutorial](http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/38721-microsoft-word-catalogue-directory-mailmerge-tutorial.html) by Paul Edstein, Word MVP

See also his [Mailmerge Tips and Tricks](http://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html) and this Microsoft Help Page.
Here is a [Microsoft Training Video](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/video-take-mail-merge-to-the-next-level-ca30f6af-8ea0-4d20-832b-97bdefdc307b?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

Here is my more general page on [Word Mail Merge](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/mailmerge.htm).

Comment: Thank you - and how do I get the Data into the Excel spreadsheet?
If I have to do that manually, I can also just keep the Excel document and export it.

Comment: Where is the data, now?

Comment: In Active Directory, like mentioned in the subject and text

Comment: See prior comment by Senor CMasMas. You can do a mail merge with as csv file or import that into Excel.